# How to update user through api in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5, eloquent

```
I'm trying to update user through api, and this is the function.
```

PUT request http://20a11140.ngrok.io/api/userregister/24 for user with id 24 for example.
I'm using postman for testing
When I pass the edited details, with name inclusive

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'string|min:6|confirmed',
            'phone' => 'string|min:6',
            'Age' => 'string',
            'Blood' => 'string',
            'Gender' => 'string',
            'Height' => 'string',
            'Weight' => 'string',
            'record' => 'string'
        ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
}

        $doc = User::find($id);

        if($request->hasFile('picture')){
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('picture')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('picture')->storeAs('public/images', $fileNameToStore);
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        $doc->name = $request->input('name');
          $doc->email = $request->input('email');
          $doc->phone = $request->input('phone');
          if($request->hasFile('picture')){
            $doc->picture = $fileNameToStore;
            }



           $doc->save();

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Success',

        ]);

    }
```

When I pass the edited details, with name inclusive and email, and every required info.
When I run this code, I get this

```
"{\"name\":[\"The name field is required.\"],\"email\":[\"The email field is required.\"]}"
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: Are you definitely issuing a PUT request? Is it encoded properly, and if so in what type? Clearly the data isn't arriving at the controller as you're expecting, so I'd suggest looking at the data you're sending, or perhaps try debugging in the controller to capture what is actually received.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Updating a User through the api in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196681/updating-a-user-through-the-api-in-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere you are wrong with sending data.

If you are using API middlewares then you will have to send data with Body Raw Json using Postman.

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "9bc0d91b-83e7-4ccf-a561-ac191c21e869",
        "name": "Laravel",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "http://20a11140.ngrok.io/api/userregister/24",
            "request": {
                "method": "PUT",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\n\t\"name\" : \"BHaskar Rajoriya\",\n\t\"email\" : \"brn.rajoriya@gmail.com\"\n}",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "http://20a11140.ngrok.io/api/userregister/24",
                    "protocol": "http",
                    "host": [
                        "20a11140",
                        "ngrok",
                        "io"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "userregister",
                        "24"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
    ],
    "protocolProfileBehavior": {}
}
```

Use this postman collection.

Comment: It works when I use Body raw. But it doesn't work in my react native project

Comment: is this your way to hit API https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60196681/updating-a-user-through-the-api-in-laravel ?